# Unable to set Width of Column in GridView ASP.NET (No DataSource for GridView)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, column-width

An error popped up upon running the application.

I'm trying to set the Width of the First Column of my GridView but i can't do it.

Rows, Columns, Data of this GridView is not bounded to any DataSource.

```
//By Class Statistics

int A1Available = get.countAvailA1();
int A1Alloted = get.countUnavailA1();
int B1Available = get.countAvailB1();
int B1Alloted = get.countUnavailB1();
int B2Available = get.countAvailB2();
int B2Alloted = get.countUnavailB2();
int C1Available = get.countAvailC1();
int C1Alloted = get.countUnavailC1();

DataTable dtClass = new DataTable();
dtClass.Columns.Add("Class");
dtClass.Columns.Add("A1");
dtClass.Columns.Add("B1");
dtClass.Columns.Add("B2");
dtClass.Columns.Add("C1");

DataRow r;
r = dtClass.NewRow();
r["Class"] = "Number of Available Beds";
r["A1"] = A1Available.ToString();
r["B1"] = B1Available.ToString();
r["B2"] = B2Available.ToString();
r["C1"] = C1Available.ToString();
dtClass.Rows.Add(r);

r = dtClass.NewRow();
r["Class"] = "Number of Unavailable Beds";
r["A1"] = A1Alloted.ToString();
r["B1"] = B1Alloted.ToString();
r["B2"] = B2Alloted.ToString();
r["C1"] = C1Alloted.ToString();
dtClass.Rows.Add(r);

bedStats.DataSource = dtClass;
bedStats.DataBind();   
bedStats.Columns[1].HeaderStyle.Width = new Unit(55, UnitType.Percentage);
```

Used this code to set the Width. Is there any other way to? Doesn't have be bothered about the value, just setting the Width..

```
bedStats.Columns[1].HeaderStyle.Width = new Unit(55, UnitType.Percentage);
```

Image of Error

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, `bedStats.Columns[1]` seems to be the issue. If you but a break point on this line, and inspect the `bedStats` columns before trying to access the second column ([1]). What do you see?

Comment: I added a break point, looking at autos, may i ask what is needed? @FredrikLundin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting column values will only work with `TemplateField` and `BoundField` columns. Autogenerated columns are not part the column collection in the GridView. If you want to color the Headers you need to use the `OnRowDataBound` event. Only then you can access the columns.

```
protected void bedStats_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Width = new Unit(55, UnitType.Percentage);
        e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = Color.Pink;
    }
}
```